# Error utilizando Volley en Android Studio

Tags: php, android, webservice, volley

Hola como tengo entendido para enviar un url hacia un web service se utilizan parametros para utilizarlos en la consulta a la base de datos. Pero en el caso de querer traer todo de una tabla y no enviar parametros como se utilizaria el JsonObjectRequest? Gracias.

```
String url = "http://192.168.0.69/webservice/comercios.php";

jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
 null,this,this);

request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Ahí es donde dice "POST" que tendría que decir si es que no le enviamos parametros? Gracias

Comment: para mostrarse en un RecyclerView?

Comment: Para traerlos en un listView

Answer (score 0):

Solamente ingresas el url. Un ejemplo

```
 JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url ,         // Es con un json array request y se indica el url
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response.length() > 0) {                         
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);   // luego pasa a json object
                                TuPojo item = new TuPojo();                    // obtienes tu POJO
                                item.setTitulo(data.getString("titulo"));      // y le asignas los parametros obtenidos, aquí un ej (titulo)
                                 ...                                          
                                listdata.add(item);
                                // listata es el ArrayList de TuPojo
                            } catch (JSONException e){
                               e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                           }, new Response.ErrorListener() ...

                   Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(arrayRequest);
```